# Get all points in a tile in Matplotlib's hexbin

Tags: events, matplotlib, interactive

I would like to create an interactive hexbin plot where clicking on a tile results in printing all points in that tile. How can I retrieve those indices? I know that I can set `picker=True` when calling `hexbin` to enable events, create a callback function `on_pick(event)`,  then register it with `gcf().mpl_connect(on_pick)`, but I don't know how to interpret the `event` I receive.  Were I using `scatter` instead of `hexbin`, `event.ind` would correspond to my goal, but the contents seem to be different under `hexbin`.

Thanks!